# S3からRedShiftにcopyしてもデータが空になってしまう

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

S3からRedShiftにデータを格納したいのですが、データが空の状態で格納されてしまいます。 
（サーバー情報など一部データを伏せております）

・S3に格納してあるデータ

```
{"message":"unixtime:1445847958\tdatetime:26/Oct/2015:17:25:58 +0900\tx-forwaded-for:****\thost:****\tsize:0\tresponse_time:606\tstatus:200\tserver:****\tHost:****:GET\tpath:****\tprotocol:****\treferer:-\t}
```

redshift側ではcopyコマンドで `format as json 'auto' gzip` を指定しております。

おそらくデータのフォーマットを変更してあげればいいと思うのですが、 
どのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか？

お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: JSONのフォーマットがおかしいですが記載内容は正しいですか？